# Xamarin.Forms C# property not updating in Device.StartTimer

Tags: c#, mvvm, xamarin.forms, properties, inotifypropertychanged

I want to create a app that counts down the selectedtime. But I am having a weird problem and I do not know what I am doing wrong.

Here is my timer, it will be called everytime the property of the picker changes. When I select a time the code only removes 1 second and then it doesn't update anymore.

```
Picker.PropertyChanged += (sender, e) =>
            {
                if (e.PropertyName == TimePicker.TimeProperty.PropertyName)
                {
                    Device.StartTimer(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1), () =>
                    {
                        clockViewModel.SelectedTime = Picker.Time.Subtract(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));
                        return true;
                    });
                }
            };
```

I also tried to print a value that kept updating in the value:

```
public int i = 0;

        private void StartTimer()
        {
            Device.StartTimer(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1), () =>
            {
                clockViewModel.SelectedTime = Picker.Time.Subtract(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));
                label.Text = i;
                i++;
                return true;
            });
        }
```

The value kept increasing, so I know for sure that it is doing something.

This is my modelview:

```
public class ClockViewModel : BaseViewModel
    {
        private TimeSpan selectedTime;

        public TimeSpan SelectedTime
        {
            get => selectedTime;
            set
            {
                selectedTime = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
    }
```

Anyone know what I am doing wrong here?

Answer (score 3):

The timer runs in a different thread. If you want to run something on the main thread, where the UI is, then you have to use the `Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread()` method. Like this:

```
Device.StartTimer(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1), () =>
{
    Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread (() => 
    {
        clockViewModel.SelectedTime = Picker.Time.Subtract(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));
        label.Text = i;
    });

    i++;
    return true;
});
```